# Azure Appfabric just doesn't cut it

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an ASP.NET web site project that runs fine when deployed to Azure, but will not run locally in the Compute Emulator.  Seems like if it works in Azure it ought to work in the Compute Emulator, but I guess that's not a high priority to the SDK developers or something.

Anyway, if you try to run the Azure web role locally in debugger you get this:

[image: Error attaching to debugger]

If you Ctrl-F5 (run w/o debug) you get a generic 500 - internal server error.

Googling suggests it's probably something in Web.config that the Compute Emulator (or the local IIS)doesn't like.

Anyone had a problem like this?

P.S. I can run the website project fine locally if I set the website as the startup project (i.e. leave Azure emulators out of it)

Comment: * image stolen from someone else's post, but essentially same error *

Comment: Are you running visual studio as an administrator?

Comment: And no, we have not experienced this issue. We use the Azure emulator just fine on several large projects.  You have a configuration error somewhere, blaming the emulator is not a good way to solve the problem :)

Comment: You certainly cannot debug if you can't view the URI directly. The Azure Emulator works fine for us. You need to fix your configuration errors. Check your windows event log to see what the 500 error is.

Comment: FYI, I think everywhere this question says "AppFabric" it's actually talking about the compute emulator.

Comment: Admin: yes. Maybe I'm being imprecise when I use the term "AppFabric" here, but the point remains: you have to be able to develop in an environment that closely simulates the env. in the cloud. Otherwise your testing is questionable and you don't know what you have.

Comment: Did you follow the advice on the error message and try running just the website outside the emulator?  That often shows you the real issue.  Also, review:  http://dunnry.com/blog/2011/07/14/HowToDiagnoseWindowsAzureErrorAttachingDebuggerErrors.aspx

Comment: can you repro in a sample project that you can share with us? will help us diagnose your issue...  I too have no issues running sites in the Emulator and can't seem to repro your issue :(

Answer (score 0):

like all have said - run outside emulator to verify web.config is correct.  Other issue of note is that emulator is running on port :82 - typically means you already have one or two sites running in local IIS - disable/stop this sites and try running again.

Finally, when the emulator launches, open IIS manager, you should see the new site, try browsing to the site from IIS.  Make sure customErrors=Off and debug=true.

Comment: Actually, I normally do all my work without running in the emulator. I'm not stuck.  It runs and debugs fine when I set the website project as the startup.

And it deploys (tho slow) and runs fine in Azure.  The only thing that does not work is running in the emulator.  

I imagine it probably IS something in the web.config that the emulator doesn't like, but I haven't had time to figure out exactly what.

Comment: Dunnry - thanks for that article link. Good read! Unfortunately, my log shows no details on the error.  Just the 500 error.